# Is there a data loss while switching to darkmode

Tags: android, kotlin

When the Dark mode is enabled using the `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES` in kotlin, the activity or the fragment is recreated. If we are calling an API in the same class it will be recalled. Is there a way to eliminate recalling the API.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to handle this is by using `ViewModel`.

As the official documentation says:

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in
>   a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive
>   configuration changes such as screen rotations.

What it means, is that your ViewModel will survive your UI recreation and there will be no data loss or API double calls.

Create your `ViewModel` class.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun callAPI() {
        // call you're API here
    }
}
```

Just obtain your `ViewModel` once in Fragment's `onCreate()` lifecycle callback.

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

As you want that your API call will be done onle once per screen, make it in the ViewModel's construcor (for example).

```
init {
    callAPI()
}
```

Please read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin).

Comment: I am doing the same thing but when I am changing the theme the fragment is recreated and the API is called twice.

Comment: @PathuriNaveena, try to do this - `ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[MyViewModel::class.java]`